# How to escape HTML in JS/ERB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

There is the following code in some_view.js.erb:

```
tr.append($('<td><%= render partial: "order_status_form", locals: { order: order } %></td>'));
```

As result we get the following code:

```
tr.append($('<td><form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/orders/1/change_status" class="edit_order" data-remote="true" id="edit_order_1" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" /></div>  <div class='row'>
    <select data-method="patch" data-remote="true" data-url="/admin/orders/1/change_status" id="order_order_status_id" name="order[order_status_id]"><option selected="selected" value="1">New</option>
    <option value="2">Preparing</option>
  </div>
</form>
</td>'));
```

But as you can see my html in append is not valid, because there are single quotes in html code. How can I fix it? I can't edit code of partial. Can I escape it or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Try this.     

$("tr").append("<td><%= escape_javascript(render 'order_status_form', order: order )%></td>");
```